# Distributed jmeter test, with 20 VMs running jmeter-server. Kicks off first thread for each VM during ramp up, across all VMs at the same time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am running a test using a high memory footprint script (don't ask) and I have been given 20 VMs to run jmeter-server. 20 VMs and 8 threads per VM. Ugh. 160 threads total

When I start the test from the Master, every server kicks off the first thread at the same moment (yep of course). But this causes 20 Txn to hammer the system at once.

[image: threads starting up at the same moments]

I thought to put a uniform random timer inside a "once only" controller, for about half the length of Pacing but the graph is still showing thread starts and ends about the same time.

[image: JMeter uniform random timer inside once only controller]

[image: classic sawtooth graph of hits cadence doom]

Eventually it evens out because of random think time. Why isn't the uniform random timer doing what I expect it to do?

There must be some assumption I'm missing. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your Uniform Random Timer really works, according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) it really adds a delay only when it's run in context of a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers). It means no sampler = no delay.

You need to add a Sampler, i.e. [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) one under the Once Only Controller and make the Uniform Random Timer the child of this Sampler.

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)